# How to write a function that reliably exits (with a specified status) the current process?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, zsh

The script below is a minimal (albeit artificial) illustration of the problem.

```
## demo.sh

exitfn () {
    printf -- 'exitfn PID: %d\n' "$$" >&2
    exit 1
}

printf -- 'script PID: %d\n' "$$" >&2

exitfn | :

printf -- 'SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS (0)\n' >&2

exitfn

printf -- 'SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS (1)\n' >&2
```

In this example script, `exitfn` stands for a function whose job entails terminating the current process<sup>1</sup>.

Unfortunately, as implemented, `exitfn` does not accomplish this mission reliably.

If one runs this script, the output looks like this:

```
% bash ./demo.sh
script PID: 26731
exitfn PID: 26731
SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS (0)
exitfn PID: 26731
```

(Of course, the value shown for PID will be different with each invocation.)

The key point here is that, on the first invocation of the `exitfn` function, the `exit 1` command in its body ***fails to terminate the execution of the enclosing script*** (as evidenced by the execution of the first `printf` command immediately following).  In contrast, on the second invocation of `exitfn`, this `exit 1` command does bring the script's execution to an end (as evidenced by the fact that the second `printf` command is not executed).

The only difference between the two invocations of `exitfn` is that the first one occurs as the first component of a two-component pipeline, while the second one is a "standalone" invocation.

I am puzzled by this.  I had expected that `exit` would have the effect of killing the current process (i.e. the one with PID given by `$$`).  Obviously, this is not always true.

Be that as it may, is there a way to write `exitfn` so that it exits the surrounding script even when invoked within a pipeline?

---

Incidentally, the script above is also a valid zsh script, and produces the same result:

```
% zsh ./demo.sh
script PID: 26799
exitfn PID: 26799
SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS (0)
exitfn PID: 26799
```

I'd be interested in the answer to this question for zsh as well.

---

Finally, I should point out that implementing `exitfn` like this does not work at all:

```
exitfn () {
    printf -- 'exitfn PID: %d\n' "$$" >&2
    exit 1
    kill -9 "$$"
}
```

...because, under all circumstances, the `exit 1` command is always the last line of that function that gets executed.  (*Replacing* `exit 1` with `kill -9 $$` is not acceptable: I want to control the script's exit status, and its output to stderr.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>In practice, such a function would perform other tasks, such as diagnostics logging, or cleanup operations, before terminating the current process.</sup>

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: [exit shell script from a subshell](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/48533)

Comment: Also related: [What is the differences between "kill -PIPE $$" vs. "exit 1"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/478281)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had expected that `exit` would have the effect of killing the current process (i.e. the one with PID given by `$$`)

“The current process” is not the same thing as “the process with PID given by `$$`”. `exit` exits the current *subshell*, or the original shell if it isn't called in a subshell.

Certain constructs, such as the content of `( … )` (grouping with subshell), command substitutions (`$(…)` or `` `…` ``), and each side of a pipe (or only the left-hand side in some shells), run in a subshell. A subshell behaves as if it was a separate process created with [`fork()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)), and it usually is implemented this way (some shells don't use subprocesses in some circumstances, as a performance optimization). The subshell has its own copy of variables, its own redirections, etc. Calling `exit` exits the subshell, just like the `exit()` function in the standard C library exits the process. For more about subshells, see [What is a subshell (in the context of the documentation of make)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23698/what-is-a-subshell-in-the-context-of-the-documentation-of-make), [What is the exact difference between a "subshell" and a "child process"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421020/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-subshell-and-a-child-process) and [Is $() a subshell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442692/is-a-subshell).

`$$` is always the process ID of the original shell process. It doesn't change in a subshell. Some shells have a variable that changes in a subshell, for example `$BASHPID` in bash and mksh, or `${.sh.subshell}` in ksh or `$ZSH_SUBSHELL` or `$sysparams[pid]` in zsh¹.

> is there a way to write `exitfn` so that it exits the surrounding script even when invoked within a pipeline?

Not exactly. You'll need to do more work, either at the point where the script creates subshell, or at the toplevel, or both. See [exit shell script from a subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48533/exit-shell-script-from-a-subshell) for approximations.

---

<sup>¹ beware though that contrary to other shells, `zsh` performs expansions in pipelines in the parent process (from left to right), not in each of the members of the pipelines: `zsh -c 'echo $ZSH_SUBSHELL | cat'` outputs `0` (even though that `echo` runs in a child process) and `zsh -c 'n=0; echo $((++n)) | echo $((++n))'` outputs 2.</sup>