# export env variable does not work from Makefile

Tags: shell, make

We have below task in `Makefile`:

```
test:
    export SOME_ENV=someTest
    go test -tags=integration -v -race  ./tests/integrationtest/...
```

---

on shell prompt, SOME_ENV is set and the next command(`go test`) internally picks `.someTest.env` file

```
 $ export SOME_ENV=someTest
 $ go test -tags=integration -v -race  ./tests/integrationtest/...
```

---

but the Makefile approach doesn't work

Why environment variable is not set using `Makefile` approach?

Note: we have another tasks in Makefile that should not be influence with this export

Comment: Related: [What is a subshell (in the context of the documentation of make)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23698/what-is-a-subshell-in-the-context-of-the-documentation-of-make)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Each line in a recipe is executed using a separate shell invocation. Thus

```
export SOME_ENV=someTest
```

is executed, then in a new shell,

```
go test ...
```

and the latter doesn’t see the environment variable.

You should export the variable using Make’s constructs:

```make
export SOME_ENV := someTest

test:
        go test ...
```

or specify the variable inline:

```make
test:
        SOME_ENV=someTest go test ...
```

or ensure both lines are run in the same shell:

```make
test:
        export SOME_ENV=someTest && \
        go test ...
```

Comment: I couldn't get the final approach to work. Is there btw a way to expose SOME_ENV to the rest of the commands without export?

Comment: That depends on exactly where you need to expose `SOME_ENV`. If you need to have it in child processes’ environments, you need to export it, either from Make or the shell.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen kitt pointed out the export will take effect in a separate shell and not the one you are calling the make, his answer gave a solution if the command that preceds the export also will be run using make, but you can do something like this if you want to use it out of make:

```bash
print_my_env:
    echo 'export MY_ENV="blue"'
```

then:

```bash
eval "$(make print_my_env)"
```

now if you run echo "$MY_ENV" you should get your env.